# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo for Facebook SDK Samples

Tags: facebook, instantiation

I'm trying to go through the Facebook SDK samples, and have followed the installation instructions of importing the SDK and the Samples into Eclipse.  I did not copy them into workspace, and I set each project to Project>Properties>Java Comiler>JDK Compliance 1.6.  I then cleaned all files, and Eclipse shows no errors or problems in Package Explorer.

When I try to run the simplest project (no hash required) I receive these errors

```
06-02 12:18:08.703: D/AndroidRuntime(2552): Shutting down VM
06-02 12:18:08.703: W/dalvikvm(2552): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{com.facebook.samples.profilepicture/com.facebook.samples.profilepicture.ProfilePictureSampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.profilepicture.ProfilePictureSampleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.facebook.samples.profilepicture-2.apk]
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.samples.profilepicture.ProfilePictureSampleActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.facebook.samples.profilepicture-2.apk]
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
 06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
06-02 12:18:08.710: E/AndroidRuntime(2552):     ... 11 more
```

I have tried importing directly into my workspace.. same errors... I have reviewed the Android Manifest below: and see no problems... I have looked at order of  Project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export, and see nothing there.

This is driving me batty...

anyone have any idea on what I need to do?  (I'm even thinking of a fresh install of the ADT.. but I don't think that will do me any good)

Here is the Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.facebook.samples.profilepicture"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon" >
    <activity
            android:name=".ProfilePictureSampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: did a fresh install of the newest ADT, imported appropriate SDK's and still am getting the same error... But I Can SEE the class listed under the src files of the project... and it is named correctly, so I have no other ideas to try

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dinked around with this for days, but this finally got things working for me:

On the FacebookSDK project and all the sample projects, right click and select "Android Tools->Add Support Library".  Then right-click again and select "Android Tools->Fix Project Properties"

On the FacebookSDK project, go to "Properties->Java Build Path" and select the "Order and Export" tab, and make sure "android-support-v4.jar - FacebookSDK/libs" is checked.

On all the sample projects, go to "Properties->Java Build Path" and select the "Libraries" tab, press the "Add Jars..." button, and select the android-support-v4.jar file in the FacebookSDK/libs directory that you downloaded.  Now go to the "Order and Export" tab, and check "android-support-v4.jar - FacebookSDK/libs".

Now clean the FacebookSDK and all the sample projects.

At this point, at least the sample projects that do not require you to register with Facebook as a developer should work.  For example, ProfilePictureSample should work.